# sprintf() without trailing null space in C

Tags: c, string, null, printf

Is there a way to use the C sprintf() function without it adding a '\0' character at the end of its output? I need to write formatted text in the middle of a fixed width string.

Comment: Thanks, I just know that sprintf produce `\0` at the end of its output.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is no way to tell `sprintf()` not to write a trailing null. What you can do is use `sprintf()` to write to a temporary string, and then something like `strncpy()` to copy only the bytes that you want.

Comment: Or use memmove() or perhaps memcpy() rather than strncpy().

Comment: Roddy: The snprintf function always null terminates its output. If you pass a size n to snprintf, it will write at most n-1 characters followed by a trailing '\0'.

Comment: Actually this example will not add a null: char name[9] = "QQ40dude"; unsigned int i0To100 = 63; _snprintf(&name[2],2,"%d",i0To100); printf(name);// output: QQ63dude

Comment: @yanbellavance: Your example does not work as you claim and prints simply `QQ6`.

Answer (score 33):

sprintf returns the length of the string written (not including the null terminal), you could use that to know where the null terminal was, and change the null terminal character to something else (ie a space). That would be more efficient than using strncpy.

```
 unsigned int len = sprintf(str, ...);
 str[len] = '<your char here>';
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't do this with sprintf(), but you *may* be able to with snprintf(), depending on your platform.

You need to know how many characters you are replacing (but as you're putting them into the middle of a string, you probably know that anyway).

This works because some implementations of snprintf() do NOT guarantee that a terminating character is written - presumably for compatibility with functions like stncpy().

```
char message[32] = "Hello 123, it's good to see you.";

snprintf(&message[6],3,"Joe");
```

After this, "123" is replaced with "Joe".

On implementations where snprintf() guarantees null termination even if the string is truncated, this won't work. So if code portability is a concern, you should avoid this.

Most [Windows-based versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx) of snprintf() exhibit this behaviour.

But, [MacOS](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/snprintf.3.html) and BSD (and maybe linux) appear to always null-terminate.

Comment: The snprintf function always null terminates its output. After running the above code, message contains "Hello Jo".

Comment: @Greg. You're almost right... I've updated answer to reflect implementation dependence.

Comment: Wow, I never knew that differed across platforms, thanks for that.

Comment: Does anybody have any idea what the POSIX and/or C99 specifications dictate?

Comment: I believe the Specs dictate the null terminator should always be added (the idea being that strings are always null-terminated and within bounds, hence preventing buffer overflow). However most implementations differ from the standard, either by not adding \0, or adding it after the end of the buffer. See wikipedia: printf.

Comment: Although this answer calls it an implementation issue, it is certainly not _implementation defined behavior_ as C defined _implementation-defined behavior_ §3.4.2.  This is a case of non-compliance.  The _null character_ is specified to be added.  To not do so is non-compliant behavior.  Further, it is not a OS issue, buf a compiler one.  Code can work as it should with a Window's compiler, albeit perhaps not an MS one.

Comment: @chux. Mostly agree with that. My answer is 9 years old and it seems MS have finally fixed this for compliance. (strictly speaking it's the C runtime-library rather than compiler that has the issue, but the two tend to go hand in hand) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-snprintf-snprintf-l-snwprintf-snwprintf-l

Answer (score 2):

You could also use your fixed width string as a format string like this:

```
char my_fixed_width_string_format[] = "need 10 chars starting here: %10s";
char my_fixed_width_string[40];
char string_to_print[] = "abcdefghijklmnop";
sprintf(my_fixed_width_string, my_fixed_width_string_format, string_to_print;
printf(my_fixed_width_string);
```

should yield

> need 10 chars starting here: abcdefghij

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Does this prevent a trailing null from the sprintf()? or is the value at my_fixed_width_string + 41 clobbered with the null?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're writing to a fixed area, you can do it like this:

```
// pointer to fixed area we want to write to
char* s;

// number of bytes needed, not including the null
int r = snprintf(0, 0, <your va_args here>);

// char following the last char we will write - null goes here
char c = s[r + 1];

// do the formatted write
snprintf(s, r + 1, <your_va_args here>);

// replace what was overwritten
s[r + 1] = c;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option for memory constrained devices. It trades off speed for using less RAM. I sometimes have to do this to update the middle of a string that gets printed to a LCD.

The idea is that you first call snprintf with a zero sized buffer to determine which index will get clobbered by the null terminator.

You can run the below code here: https://rextester.com/AMOOC49082

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char buf[100] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
  const size_t buf_size = sizeof(buf);
  const int i = 123;

  int result = snprintf(buf, 0, "%i", i);
  if (result < 0)
  {
    printf("snprintf error: %i\n", result);
    return -1;
  }

  int clobbered_index = result; //this index will get the null term written into it

  if (result >= buf_size)
  {
    printf("buffer not large enough. required %i chars\n", result + 1);
    return -1;
  }

  char temp_char = buf[clobbered_index];
  result = snprintf(buf, buf_size, "%i", i); //add result error checking here to catch future mistakes
  buf[clobbered_index] = temp_char;

  printf("buf:%s\n", buf);

  return 0;
}
```

Prints `buf:123de`

Answer (score 0):

Actually this example will not add a null if you use snprintf:

```
char name[9] = "QQ40dude";  
unsigned int i0To100 = 63;  
_snprintf(&name[2],2,"%d",i0To100);  
printf(name);// output will be: QQ63dude
```

Comment: Unfortunately the output is `QQ6` with POSIX `snprintf(3)`.

Answer (score -3):

look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf

> printf("%.*s", 3, "abcdef") will result in "abc" being printed

Comment: the string versions of these functions differ in this respect from the non-string versions. In other words, sprintf and snprintf always append the null byte, but printf does not, so your example isn't applicable.