# How to write to the Output window in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Which function should I use to output text to the "Output" window in Visual Studio?

I tried `printf()` but it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

[OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx) function will do it.

example code

```
    void CClass::Output(const char* szFormat, ...)
{
    char szBuff[1024];
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, szFormat);
    _vsnprintf(szBuff, sizeof(szBuff), szFormat, arg);
    va_end(arg);

    OutputDebugString(szBuff);
}
```

Comment: There's still a problem with this. _vsnprintf may truncate the formatted string to fit the buffer, but if this happens the string won't be nul-terminated. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357068.

Comment: You are using the multibyte character set in your compiler options. You then need to use the multibyte versions of `WCHAR szBuff[1024]` `_vsnwprintf`

Comment: Warning 1 warning C4996: '_vsnwprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _vsnwprintf_s instead.  ;-)

Comment: Do I need to #include something to get OutputDebugString to work?

Comment: include Windows.h

Answer (score 76):

If this is for debug output then [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx) is what you want. A useful macro  :

```
#define DBOUT( s )            \
{                             \
   std::ostringstream os_;    \
   os_ << s;                   \
   OutputDebugString( os_.str().c_str() );  \
}
```

This allows you to say things like:

```
DBOUT( "The value of x is " << x );
```

You can extend this using the `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` macros to give even more information.

For those in Windows and wide character land:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

 #define DBOUT( s )            \
{                             \
   std::wostringstream os_;    \
   os_ << s;                   \
   OutputDebugStringW( os_.str().c_str() );  \
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this statement a bit? - "You can extend this using the __LINE__ and __FILE__ macros to give even more information."

Comment: @sami1592 those two macros are defined by the compiler to be the (surprise) line and file, so you can output more useful logs containing the line and file automatically.

Answer (score 22):

Use the [`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362(VS.85).aspx) function or the [`TRACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wyz8787(VS.80).aspx) macro (MFC) which lets you do `printf`-style formatting:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 16;
float z = 32.0;
TRACE( "This is a TRACE statement\n" );    
TRACE( "The value of x is %d\n", x );
TRACE( "x = %d and y = %d\n", x, y );
TRACE( "x = %d and y = %x and z = %f\n", x, y, z );
```

Comment: My compiler in Visual Studio isn't recognizing ALTTRACE2 or ALTTRACE.  Do I need to #include something? Is it because it's not an MFC project?  It's just c++ for me.

Comment: I was testing an old 3DES algorithm in Visual Studio 2017, C++. I got the code working by replacing all "printf" to "TRACE". Very good hit! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Useful tip - if you use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` then format your debug as:

```
"file(line): Your output here"
```

then when you click on that line in the output window Visual Studio will jump directly to that line of code. An example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void DBOut(const char *file, const int line, const WCHAR *s)
{
    std::wostringstream os_;
    os_ << file << "(" << line << "): ";
    os_ << s;
    OutputDebugStringW(os_.str().c_str());
}

#define DBOUT(s)       DBOut(__FILE__, __LINE__, s)
```

I wrote a blog post about this so I always knew where I could look it up:
https://windowscecleaner.blogspot.co.nz/2013/04/debug-output-tricks-for-visual-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

Use OutputDebugString instead of afxDump.

Example:

```
#define _TRACE_MAXLEN 500

#if _MSC_VER >= 1900
#define _PRINT_DEBUG_STRING(text) OutputDebugString(text)
#else // _MSC_VER >= 1900
#define _PRINT_DEBUG_STRING(text) afxDump << text
#endif // _MSC_VER >= 1900

void MyTrace(LPCTSTR sFormat, ...)
{
    TCHAR text[_TRACE_MAXLEN + 1];
    memset(text, 0, _TRACE_MAXLEN + 1);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, sFormat);
    int n = _vsntprintf(text, _TRACE_MAXLEN, sFormat, args);
    va_end(args);
    _PRINT_DEBUG_STRING(text);
    if(n <= 0)
        _PRINT_DEBUG_STRING(_T("[...]"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though [`OutputDebugString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx) indeed prints a string of characters to the debugger console, it's not exactly like `printf` with regard to the latter being able to format arguments using the `%` notation and a variable number of arguments, something `OutputDebugString` does not do.

I would make the case that the [`_RPTFN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/rpt-rptf-rptw-rptfw-macros) family of macros, with `_CRT_WARN` argument at least, is a better suitor in this case -- it formats the principal string much like `printf`, writing the result to debugger console.

A minor (and strange, in my opinion) caveat with it is that it requires *at least one argument* following the format string (the one with all the `%` for substitution), a limitation `printf` does *not* suffer from.

For cases where you need a `puts` like functionality -- no formatting, just writing the string as-is -- there is `_RPTF0` (which *ignores* arguments following the first, another strange caveat). Or `OutputDebugString` of course.

And by the way, there is also everything from `_RPT1` to `_RPT5` but I haven't tried them. Honestly, I don't understand why provide so many procedures all doing essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

wstring outputMe = L"can" + L" concatenate\n";
OutputDebugString(outputMe.c_str());
```

Comment: `#include <string>`