# How to print a two dimensional array in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, arrays, logging, cocos2d-x

I have a two-dimensional array that I want to print to the **output** of visual studio to see the result each time I modify that, I tried using `std::cout` and it does not work, if I use `CCLOG` the function will automatically write a newline each time it's called that and it's not a two-dimensional array pretty solution, I also tried `CClog` not sure what's the difference with `CCLOG` but this time it even give a compiling error :(

like I want the output be:

```
1,2,4,4,5
5,5,4,3,0
4,4,4,4,7
6,6,6,6,6
```

Here is what I tried:

```
void HelloWorld::PrintBrickArray() {
    CCLOG("will print brick array");
    std::cout << "===Begin of Array ====" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_Y; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_X; j++) {
            //CCLog("%d", this->brickArray[i][j]);
            std::cout << this->brickArray[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "*****END OF Array *****" << std::endl;
    std::cout.flush();
}
```

How to do that with coco2dx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CCLOG` or `cocos2d::log` uses the Visual Studio's Debug windows, which is different to write to console where `std::cout` works.

Therefore, there are two ways to get rid of your problem: writing to console using `std::cout` or writing to output windows using different methods than `CCLOG`

First choice, you have to change your project type from Win32 Application Project to Win32 Console Project. This is kind of going around with Visual Studio stuffs, and in most cases, your project is created automatically via cocos2d's console. You can see [this post](http://hdrlab.org.nz/articles/windows-development/changing-a-windows-app-to-a-console-app-in-visual-studio/). I'm not recommend this way IMO.

Second choice, use your own code to write to output which discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149620/how-to-write-to-the-output-window-in-visual-studio).

There is another way that you can use `std::string` and `std::ostringstream` to "print" your variables to buffer, and then just print your string to output windows via `CCLOG`

`CCLOG` is a little bit wrapping the code to make it convenience where we log resources checking, errors, file processing, etc which usually occur when run time. If not in those cases, you should probably set break points to view what the values are instead.

**Edited**: Since you chose the second approach, I would recommend using `std::ostringstream` than `sprintf`, and using `CCLog` instead of `OutputDebugString` (because you just print it out and independent OS<strike>, no need extra arguments</strike>)

Here is an example code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream> // for ostringstream
#include <Windows.h> // for OutputDebugStringA
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    // Assuming that you have this 2d array
    vector< vector<int> > arr2d;
    arr2d.push_back({ 2,2,1,4 });
    arr2d.push_back({ 2,4,1,5 });
    arr2d.push_back({ 2,4,7,2 });
    arr2d.push_back({ 3,2,0,1 });

    ostringstream buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2d.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2d[i].size(); j++)
        {
            buffer << arr2d[i][j] << '\t';
        }
        buffer << endl;
    }

    // Assuming that you use OutputDebugString for windows-only
    //OutputDebugStringA(buffer.str().c_str());

    // I recommend this
    cocos2d::log(buffer.str().c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Now, `buffer` works nearly the same as `cout`, it just "print" to buffer instead, then you can get one using `str()`. But `cocos2d::log` use C-style string, so `c_str()` will get rid of the problem

See more about `std::ostringstream` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/?kw=ostringstream)

Comment: hey, I tried to use `sprintf` and `string +` to implement the second choice you give, but none came out right, can you give a more specific example, really a newbie of c++, thanks