# sprintf removes the previous value, after calling twice in C

Tags: c

This is the code, I have, i cover the message into hex-representation in string, but after second times covering, the m1_hex accidentally become empty string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

typedef unsigned char text;
typedef const size_t slen;

void turnCharToHexString(text *pt, text *ht, slen size){
  for(size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < size; ++i, j+=2){
    sprintf(ht + j, "%02x", pt[i] & 0xff);
  }
  printf("The msg %s in hex is %s\n", pt, ht);
}

int main(){

  text* m1 = "I owe you $2000.";
  text* m2 = "I owe you $3000.";

  slen sm1 = strlen(m1);

  text m1_hex[sm1 * 2];
  text m2_hex[sm1 * 2];

  turnCharToHexString(m1, m1_hex, sm1);
  printf("what is m1_hex (1): '%s'\n", m1_hex);

  turnCharToHexString(m2, m2_hex, sm1);
  printf("what is m1_hex (2): '%s'\n", m1_hex);
  printf("what is m2_hex (1): '%s'\n", m2_hex);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This is the output, what is m1_hex (2) prints empty string, even I didnt modify anything

```
the output:
The msg I owe you $2000. in hex is 49206f776520796f752024323030302e
what is m1_hex (1): '49206f776520796f752024323030302e'
The msg I owe you $3000. in hex is 49206f776520796f752024333030302e
what is m1_hex (2): '' //disappear
what is m2_hex (1): '49206f776520796f752024333030302e'
```

Comment: A character array must have N+1 characters to be able to store a string of length N.  This is because strings are terminated by a null character.  `strlen(s)` bytes is not enough to store string `s`; you need `char array[strlen(s) + 1]`.

Comment: `m1_hex` size is not enough to store null terminator.

Comment: @Kaz thank you so much, I didnt know about the null terminator, it solves the problem

Comment: @dimich true, adding 1 solves the issue

Comment: What resources are you using to learn C? The null terminator is an incredibly important topic in string handling in C, so it's amazing you haven't been informed by your learning resources.

Comment: @Kaz sorry, my school focus too much in the concurrency programming, solving some math equation faster, barely mention string, which I know is an important and complex topic

Comment: What textbook is your school following, if any?

Comment: @Kaz C Modern C Book by Jens Gustedt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
text m1_hex[sm1 * 2 + 1];
text m2_hex[sm1 * 2 + 1];
```

As the comments have mentioned, this is becuase the null terminator,

check this post here
[sprintf() without trailing null space in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357068/sprintf-without-trailing-null-space-in-c)

> There is no way to tell sprintf() not to write a trailing null. What you can do is use sprintf() to write to a temporary string, and then something like strncpy() to copy only the bytes that you want.

You may have that string temporarily there, but the following scanf will discard the previous store.

Comment: Can you explain why this null terminator causes the m1_hex to disappear?

Comment: When you don't have enough room in `m2_hex[]` for the `'\0'` character to fit, and since you declare `m1_hex[]` and `m2_hex[]` sequentially on the stack (and the stack grows down), the `'\0'` becomes the 1st character in `m1_hex[]`  causing it, by definition, to hold the empty-string (first char is `'\0'`)

Comment: @BiotieriaA  think of a normal stack; m1_hex [] gets pushed in, and then m2_hex gets pushed in. However, the end of m2_hex is the head of m1_hex; for placing the '\0', h1_hex's head gets re-write by sprintf() with '\0'.